# msyql query to return number of inner joins restricted by a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query to try to count the number of comments made within 30 minutes of a post getting made. There are two tables, `posts` and `comments` which are `INNER JOIN`ed on `posts.id` and `comments.post_id` like so:

```
SELECT id, count(post_id) as num_comm from posts
  INNER JOIN comments on id = post_id
  WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(posts.time_posted) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(comments.time_posted)) < (30 * 60)
    AND comments.reply_to_id = 0
  GROUP BY id
  ORDER BY num_comm ASC;
```

The problem I'm having is that the query is returning the the total number of `num_comm` results and not just the count of those comments that were made within 30 minutes of the original post and that has `comments.reply_to_id` set to 0.

How do I change the query to return only the number of comments that meet the criteria in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: The `WHERE` close *does* apply to the calculations for the `count()`.  You are perhaps misinterpreting the results.  Or perhaps the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` calculation is wrong (without sample data, one really cannot say).

Comment: The resultant num_comm count has the same counts whether I have the time calculation in it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, the post is posted before the comment.  So, your value is always negative.  Try:

```
SELECT id, count(*) as num_comm 
FROM posts p INNER JOIN
     comments c
     ON p.id = c.post_id
WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(c.time_posted) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.time_posted)) < (30 * 60) AND
      c.reply_to_id = 0
GROUP BY p.id
ORDER BY num_comm ASC;
```

I don't really like the conversion to Unix timestamps.  I think the code is much clearer as:

```
WHERE c.time_posted < p.time_posted + interval 30 minute AND
      c.reply_to_id = 0
```

Comment: Ah, crap. Had a couple of drinks tonight. Thanks!

Comment: As an aside, is there a good tutorial for handling time calculation with timestamps? I've had a hell of a time finding one so that's why I did the unix_timestamp() function.

Comment: @StevieD . . . I don't actually know of a good tutorial, but I do find myself referencing the date/time functions page a lot in MySQL.